# GCP can't create multi-zone managed instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Whenever I try to create a multi-zone managed instance group I get the error:

```
Invalid value for field 'resource.instanceTemplate': 'projects/[PROJECT_ID]/global/instanceTemplates/[Template-Name]'. InstanceTemplate should be usable in all selected zones.
```

The InstanceTemplate boot disk is a custom image set to Multi-regional eu (also tried regional europe-west2). The source disk for the image is an instance in europe-west2-c. The location of the instance group is Multiple zones with a region of europe-west2.

I have tried every possible settings for the image, instance template and managed instance group but always get the above error. There is nothing in creating the InstanceTemplate about zones. All of this is done via the web console.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the document to create [the template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) and [managed instance groups MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances).

To replicate your issue, I have follow below steps in console:

- I have selected one Disk from europe-west1-c
- Create Image at eu
- Create instance template  (machine type n1-standard-1)
- Create the MIG at europe-west2

My MIG created without any issue.

As your error suggest your template is not valid for the regions you have selected. This may be related to machine type you have selected. I am requesting you to review the [available regions and zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available) and check if your machine type is available at your desired zones.

NOTE: I am posting this as answer as my current reputation does not support me to comment on your post. Please feel free to let me know if I miss something or if it does not make any sense. I will edit this accordingly.

Comment: The zone I'm using is europe-west2 and the machine type is n2-standard-2 with a SSD boot disk. According to the available regions and zone document this region and all 3 zones support this configuration. But I'll try in another region.

Comment: While reviewing [the document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available) for europe-west2 I notice there are three zones under it (europe-west2-a/b/c). Also the document says europe-west2-a and europe-west2-c has the [N2 machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n2_machine_types) with up to 80 vCPUs and 640 GB of memory but the **europe-west2-b** does not have N2 machine types.

Comment: So you can either change the machine type (which is available to all three zone) or change the zone (something like europe-west4). Or the last option is you can select the location as "Multiple zones" ,Region: "europe-west2", then click on "Configure zones" and deselect the "europe-west2-b" then after all other configuration create the MIG. Hope this helps